# Widget update data properly

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I've made a widget which fetches `Codable` data and it's working just fine in the simulator **ONLY**. The widget updates within *30 seconds or less* after the data has changed. I've set a 5 minute update limit (I understand it's called far less frequently). It's working actually really great in the simulator without any kind of background data fetches and updates in less time than I set in `getTimeline`. Then I ran into an issue on a a real test device.

The data won't update anywhere between 2-10+ mins while testing a real device, in the snapshot it's updated and can see the new data changes but not in the widget on springboard. I don't understand why the simulator works just fine but not a real device. The Widget is definitely being updated when the data changes but only in the *Simulator* so am I suppose to fetch data in the background?

I've come across this [Keeping a Widget Up To Date | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date). I'm still very new to Swift and SwiftUI so this is a little bit harder for me to grasp. I'm trying to understand the section `Update After Background Network Requests Complete` to update my `Codeable` data. My guess is the simulator is different from a real device and I need to fetch data in the background for the must up to date data?

The end goal is to have the widget update as frequently as possible with the most current data. I'm not sure I even need the background data fetch?

My data model for my widget as an example (which is working fine)

```swift
class DataModel {
    var data: DataClass = DataClass(results: []))
    
    func sessions(_ completion: @escaping (DataClass -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "URL HERE") else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(DataClass.self, from: data) {
                    self.data = response
                    completion(self.data)
                    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "Widget")
                }
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

My `getTimeline` calling the data model

```swift
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    let model = DataModel()
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
    let currentDate = Date()
    let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: currentDate)!
    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, model: model)
    entries.append(entry)
    model.sessions {_ in
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

I have this for my background network request

```swift
import Foundation
import WidgetKit

class BackgroundManager : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    
    var completionHandler: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    private lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "widget-bundleID")
        config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
        return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()
    
    func update() {
        let task = urlSession.downloadTask(with: URL(string: "SAME URL FROM DATA MODEL HERE")!)
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession ,downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print (location)
    }
    
    func  urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
        self.completionHandler!()
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "Widget")
        print("Background update")
    }
}
```

Then in my Widget I set `.onBackgroundURLSessionEvents()`. I never see any background updates or errors in the console. This seems very wrong, the `Codable` data will never be updated? How do I properly update my data in the background?

```swift
struct Some_Widget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Widget"
    let backgroundData = BackgroundManager()

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            SomeWidget_WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Widget")
        .description("Example widget.")
        .onBackgroundURLSessionEvents { (sessionIdentifier, completion) in
            if sessionIdentifier == self.kind {
                self.backgroundData.update()
                self.backgroundData.completionHandler = completion
                print("background update")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Five minutes is too frequent to attempt updates. Try setting it to 15 minutes or more.

Comment: I realize that but it has to update more frequently than every 15 minutes. I did see Apple recommended a min time of 5 minutes in between.

Comment: They recommend 5 minutes between *timeline entries*. There is no official limit for how often you can refresh the whole timeline, but Apple devs in the forums have said that anything more than 4x/hour will be throttled for sure.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Question solved.

Comment: why do you have `reloadTimelines` on the `sessions` function? it's causing me an infinite loop because it calls `gettimeline` which then calls `sessions`